# Link to Application Page in Sidebar

Tags: deployment, application-pages

This sounds like a stupid question, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

From Visual Studio, I have deployed an application page to my local SharePoint server. I can get to it directly by entering the URL mysandbox/_layouts/Application/Main.aspx. However, I can't figure out how to get a link to the page on the sidebar. I see Libraries, Lists and Discussions, but nothing for Applications. Is this a configuration setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an Applications section in the Quick Launch. You have to create a Heading called Applications, then add a link to your application page under that heading. Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Quick Launch (or Navigation if you have publishing features enabled).